# ldflags is ignored when building go project

Tags: go

I want to have multiple binaries in one repository, but also set the version via `ldflags` option.

With just one binary in a repository I have no problem, it works, but with the new structure for multiple binaries it doesn't seem to work.

I have set up a simple project on [github](https://github.com/divadpoc/go-test) .

The structure is simple

```
cmd/
- server/main.go
- service/main.go
libcommon/
- version.go
- ...
go.mod
Makefile
```

version.go

```
package libcommon

var (
    Version = "dev"
    Build   = "now"
)
```

Makefile

```
BUILDDIR = bin
VERSION := $(shell git describe --tags --always --dirty)
BUILD := $(shell date +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M)
LDFLAGS=-ldflags="-w -s -X 'libcommon.Version=${VERSION}' -X 'libcommon.Build=${BUILD}'"

go build ${LDFLAGS} -o $(BUILDDIR)/ ./...
```

I call `make install` and the binary is put into `bin/` directory, but when I run it it just prints out the default values, not the ones I'd assume to be in there.

Any idea on how I can get to set the version with the ldflags in this layout?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To correctly set the variable with `-ldflags` you have to qualify the variable name with the [full package import path](https://golang.org/cmd/link/):

In Makefile:

````
LDFLAGS=-ldflags="-w -s \
-X 'mymodule.com/path/to/libcommon.Version=${VERSION}' \
-X 'mymodule.com/path/to/libcommon.Build=${BUILD}'"

build: 
    go build ${LDFLAGS} -o $(BUILDDIR)/ ./...```
````